# Ubuntu 16.04 gnome-software errors

Tags: 16.04, gnome-software

Is anyone else getting this error each time that you launch gnome-software:

`Sorry, this did not work`

`no filename_to_app results to show`

After I hit the `close` button, the application appears to work fine.  But I'm not loving the error message on each launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Desktop folder and right click on the Software Install icon. Choose properties and under Command just enter gnome-software with no tags.

Comment: Thanks.  That suggestion helped me find the solution.  I had to change the `Exec` command of the gnome-software application in `/usr/share/applications`.    The default is `Exec=gnome-software %U`.  I just got rid of the `%U`.  I also use Cairo-Dock, and for the gnome-software launcher I had to put `gnome-software` in the `Command to launch on click` area.