# no filename_to_app results to show

Tags: 16.04

What I'm trying to do is install a .deb software.
I tried launching it with software install and received the error:

> Sorry, this did not work
>
> no filename_to_app results to show

So I thought my issue is related to this thread:
[Ubuntu 16.04 gnome-software errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761587/ubuntu-16-04-gnome-software-errors)

and that is why I asked for more clarification about "Choose properties and under Command..."
There is no Command section.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AkkKHWeBCU1WhPsqeY3YVI8Jn1M6UA

Thank you

Comment: You are talking about two different things. There the discussion is about modifying the launcher for Gnome Software, while you look for this tag in the proprieties of a deb file.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? Can you add some information to your question ? You are trying right click on wrong type of files - .deb file is not launch icon. Deb file is installation package which is installed by apt application.

Comment: Added more information to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install lightpack 2 from http://www.lightpack.tv/downloads.php. Currently lightpack 2 is supported by Ubuntu 14.04 and not Ubuntu 16.04 so I do not know if it will work.

Right click on deb file and select "Open with sofware installer" and click "Install" in software installer.

But before you that check if you have 32-bit of 64-bit installation of ubuntu by opening "System settings > Details" and see "OS type". If it is 64-bit, download and install 64-bit deb file instead from [here](https://github.com/woodenshark/Lightpack/releases/download/5.11.2/prismatik_5.11.2_amd64.deb).

Comment: Still getting the same error:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkkKHWeBCU1WhPsuhPqwOwDTrAp9kg

Does that mean it doesn't work? or am I installing it wrong?

Comment: Are trying this on deb file ? Try to right click on empty space around deb icon and select "Open in terminal". Run command `sudo dpkg -i prismatik_5.11.2_i386.deb`. If you are using 64-bit system dowload 64-bit deb file https://github.com/woodenshark/Lightpack/releases/download/5.11.2/prismatik_5.11.2_amd64.deb and run command `sudo dpkg -i prismatik_5.11.2_amd64.deb` and do not extract deb file.